# running more than 10 K regressions and storing coefficients

Tags: r

I have populations of 73000 neighborhoods for eight years. I need to extract the slope of linear trend for each. So I need to estimate 73000 times `y = a + b(Trend)` model. And store their slope (b) in an list. I there a special R package for that kind of problem?

Comment: You did not include a reprocible example so hard to verify, but you should be able to back these out from `lm(y ~0 +  factor(neighbourhood) + factor(neighbourhood):time)`, if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @OttoKässi trying to build a model matrix with 8*73000 columns will likely bring `glm` to its knees

Comment: Could you please let us know how your data are stored?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the neighborhood data with each neighborhood as a separate element of a list, you can use sapply().  This is assuming the you want to run a completely unrelated regression at each neighborhood.  Here's a two neighborhood example:

```r
nbr_list <- list(n1 = c(1,4,3,4,5,4,5,6), n2 = c(4,5,5,6,5,7,9,9))

get_slope <- function(y){
  slopeOut <- lm(y~I(1:8))$coefficients[2]
  slopeOut }

sapply(nbr_list, FUN=get_slope)
#> n1.I(1:8) n2.I(1:8) 
#> 0.5238095 0.7142857
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The tidyverse solution would be to use packages `broom` and `purrr` to run many regressions by group and store them into a list-column, then extract betas. The main advantage is that you can have more complex models and the entire regression outputs get stored inside the same dataframe, you need only to retrieve them after. It is best to keep all output for potential further use (e.g. if you store only slopes and you next need intercepts you need to rerun all the regressions again).

Solution with nesting would go like this:

1. Grouping your data by neighborhood.
2. Nesting those groups into a list-column.
3. Create a model column that maps the lm function then tidy to the data list-column.
4. Unnest the model list column.
5. Filter it to wanted predictor coefficient.

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(broom)

data %>% 
  group_by(neighborhood) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = .x) %>% tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(model) %>% 
  filter(term == "predictor1")
```

Or even simpler, without nesting:

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(broom)

data %>% 
  split(.$neighborhood) %>% 
  map(~lm(outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = .x)) %>% 
  map_df(tidy) %>%
  filter(term == "predictor1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to tell you to use `lme4::lmList()`, but plain old `lm` is **much** faster if you set it up right.

### sample data

```r
nn <- 73000
ny <- 8
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(
    nbr=rep(1:nn,each=ny),
    yr=rep(1:ny,nn),
    y=rnorm(nn*ny)
)
```

### with lm()

```r
Y <- matrix(dd$y,nrow=8)  ## set up matrix of response variables
yr <- dd$yr[1:8]          ## predictor variables
system.time(mm2 <- lm(Y~yr))
cc2 <- coef(mm2)
head(cc2["yr",])
## [1]  0.088903516 -0.138058182  0.006353931  0.106540632 -0.021719822
## [6] -0.020777392
```

This is more or less instantaneous (<1 second on a fast machine).

### with lme4::lmList()

This was my first thought, and might be a little easier to understand (and would work much more generally, e.g. if you had different predictor variables for each group), but is 100-1000 times slower.

```r
library(lme4)
system.time(mm <- lmList(y~yr|nbr, data=dd)) ## fit models, 34 seconds
system.time(cc <- coef(mm))  ## extract coefs, 43 seconds
head(cc$yr)
## [1]  0.088903516 -0.138058182  0.006353931  0.106540632 -0.021719822
## [6] -0.020777392
```